# R - Tall to wide data with dplyr (or, another method)

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

Say, I have the following data:

```
set.seed(10)
dat <- data_frame(
  SKU = rep(c("sku1", "sku2", "sku3"), each=4),
  invoicedate = rep(c("12/01/2019", "12/02/2019", "12/03/2019", "12/04/2019"), 3),
  cantidad = round(rnorm(12, mean = 80, sd=4), 0)
)

dat
```

How do I get to the following format?:

```
invoicedate sku1 sku2 sku3
12/01/2019  80    81   73
12/02/2019  79    82   79
12/03/2019  75    75   84
12/04/2019  78    79   83
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `library(tidyr);spread(dat, SKU, cantidad)`

Comment: I tried that before posting the question. It works on "dat" (the example dataset here) but introduces a lot of NAs in the actual dataset with 3 years of data and 1200+ SKUs.

Comment: If the original data doesn't have that particular combination, then by default it would be `NA`  Or else you may need to do a `complete`, impute those missing values and then `spread`

Comment: I did the complete and fill before "spread" but it is still filling in the NAs. I don't understand why. I thought that my code was wrong that's why I posted. I should just delete the question.

Comment: `complete` will just give the whole combination, but still if you don't have a value for that combination, the row in that other column will be NA